# How to create a pause in SAP GUI?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

After I connect to SAP GUI via Excel, I'm having problems acquiring data from SAP GUI.

The macro is too fast. If it is paused, the logic works, but without pausing, it doesn't.

I would like to include time when running in SAP GUI.

```vb
Sub Sap()

Dim Application, SapGuiAuto, Connection, session, WScrip

If Not IsObject(Application) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
    WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If
'Login
session.findbyid("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "mylogin"
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = "password"
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").SetFocus
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").caretPosition = 8
session.findbyid("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'MM02
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "mm02"
session.findbyid("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03") '——->>>>> BUT NOT WORK THIS FUNCTION

'continueing…

End Sub
```

Comment: In Excel VBA, `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")` waits for 3 seconds successfully. Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: If I use the code Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03") in excel it works yes. But I would like to use this kind of mechanism to wait a time, when the macro is running in SAP, browsing and entering excel data inside SAP. Because I don't know any other code/syntax that makes this function wait a time between the lines of the SAP macro.

Comment: You can pause for 3 seconds in Excel VBA between 2 actions in SAP GUI. At SAP GUI side, there will be a wait of 3 seconds between the 2 actions. Maybe you can tell more about the context, because I still don't understand your question.

Comment: session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr.../ctxtMARA-MSTAE").SetFocus
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr.../ctxtMARA-MSTAE").caretPosition = 2
SendKeys "^A"
SendKeys "^{Insert}"
'I need a wait time here to be able to copy the selected field. Without wait time the macro cannot copy.
'Logout
session.findbyid("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[4]/menu[12]").Select
session.findbyid("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press

Comment: I simulated pausing the lines and it works, but when the macro runs alone, it's so fast that the computer can't store the selected (copied) field in memory.

Comment: I don't understand how it can be so fast (not waiting the 3 seconds). Note that using the clipboard is often optional, maybe you can just read the field directly into a variable, and change the value of a cell with this variable? (if it's your goal to initialize data in an Excel sheet...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also another way to generate a wait in VBA.

for example:

```
Sub Sap()

Dim Application, SapGuiAuto, Connection, session, WScript
set wshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
...
wshell.run "c:\tmp\sleep_3000.vbs",1,true
'continueing…
End Sub
```

sleep_3000.vbs in c:\tmp

```
wscript.sleep 3000
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: I tried to use it but it didn't work, where I believe it's because of windows 10 or with the host.
But I liked your idea and I ended up finding another similar way and it worked really well.

Dim fromteWait
dteWait = DateAdd("s", 3, Now())
Do Until (Now() > dteWait)
loop          Thank you for your idea.

Comment: @EdenilsonWeg Did it work or did it not work? It's not clear from what you said ;)

Comment: If the path should contain spaces, the command should be supplemented as follows: wshell.run """c:\tmp\sleep_3000.vbs""",1,true